# Node ejs forEach causing a 'Content Security Policy' error

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I'm so excited to post my first Stack Overflow query. :D

I recently started a Node.js course and with that, I just want to point out I'm not doing any hardcore stuff just yet.

I have a local node server running with nodemon. I started working with ejs and discovered that a forEach loop is melting my web page for some reason.

I tried doing research and sifting through my code removing certain parts piece by piece that weren't there before the issue until the issue went away and discovered that when I take the forEach loop out of my code in my ejs file, the problem goes away.

```
//this is my .js file located in my ./routes folder

const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const admin_data = require('./admin');

router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    const products = admin_data.products;
    res.render('shop', {
        page_title: 'Shop',
        prods: products
    });
});

//nothing too hectic.

//this is my ejs file located in my ./views folder.

<% if (prods.length > 0) { %>
        <div class="grid">
            <% forEach (var products in prods) { %> //if i remove this and it's closing '}' it works fine.
            <article class="card product-item">
                <header class="card__header">
                    <h1 class="product__title">product</h1>
                </header>
                <div class="card__image">
                    <img src="" alt="A Book">
                </div>
                <div class="card__content">
                    <h2 class="product__price">$19.99</h2>
                    <p class="product__description">A very interesting book about so many even more interesting things!
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="card__actions">
                    <button class="btn">Add to Cart</button>
                </div>
            </article>
            <% } %>
        </div>
        <% } %>
```

I expect the code to render the page but instead receive an **error**:

> "SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in C:\Users\Ruan
>   Buitendag\Documents\NodeJS\Practice Server\views\shop.ejs while
>   compiling ejs" in my vscode terminal and "Content Security Policy: The
>   page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline
>   (“default-src”)" in my browser console.

EDIT: PS. I tried running the page in firefox developer edition, plain firefox and google chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in your loop. Use `forEach` this way:

```
<% prods.forEach(function(product) { %>
<article class="card product-item">
    <header class="card__header">
       <h1 class="product__title">product</h1>
    </header>
    <div class="card__image">
       <img src="" alt="A Book">
    </div>
    <div class="card__content">
        <h2 class="product__price">$19.99</h2>
        <p class="product__description">A very interesting book about so many even more interesting things!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card__actions">
        <button class="btn">Add to Cart</button>
    </div>
</article>
<% }) %>
```

Alternatively you can use for...of loop like this:

```
<% for (var product of prods) { %>
...
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you.
Super weird though cause I was following a udemy course and did exactly what the instructor did and his was fine. 
I ended up using your alternative solution and it worked perfectly.